# Which Eclipse version should I use for Google GWT and Google App Engine development?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Ganymede, probably. But there are so many different ones. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse GWT plugin [doesn't yet support Galileo](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html), so use the latest Ganymede release (3.4 SR2). The [comparison page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/ganymede/sr2) can help you decide which particular version to use.

I'd probably take the classic version unless you know you only want to do GWT development. Of course you can always pull additional packages from the update site so it doesn't really make much difference (it's just easier to add than remove).

If you can't download a package, check out the [Eclipse torrents](http://build.eclipse.org/technology/phoenix/torrents/). You can pick the package/platform. I just tried to get the Java EE Cocoa package and it started fine.

Comment: Ganymede is no longer available for download. "Eclipse downloads - file unavailable The selected file is invalid, or it is no longer available for download. This happens when the file is part of a nightly or development build. If so, please return to the project's home page and download a newer version."

Comment: Are you trying to download the Mac Cocoa version? downloads for all the other platforms are still available.

Comment: @Ben the OP is trying to download the Cocoa version, which is not available on the download page you reference (try clicking on any of the Cocoa links)

Answer (score 2):

The plugin for Eclipse 3.5 has just been released.  So you can now use Galileo.

Answer (score 0):

I use Eclipse 3.4.1, it works fine for me. Been using it to develop my companys product for a while.
I can't imagine that there should be any problem using a different version though.